# Попарное сложение чисел в списке

Tags: python

Даны два списка чисел: [5, 2, 4] и [2, 4, 7]
Требуется сложить их между собой так, чтобы на выходе получилось трехзначное число в виде такого же списка -> [7, 7, 1]
Так как 524 + 247 = 771

Я пытаюсь сделать что-то вроде такого, но не получается:

```
def add_list(a, b):
  for i in range(len(a)):
    if (a[i]+b[i]) > 9:
      s.append((a[i] + b[i]) - 10)
      s.append((a[i-1] + b[i-1]) + 1)
    else:
      s.append(a[i] + b[i])
  return s

a = [5, 2, 4]
b = [2, 4, 7]

add_list(a, b)
```

Нужно учитывать, что при если при сложении чисел получается больше 9, то в этой ячейке нужно оставить единицы, а десятки перенести на ячейку влево, при этом, если такая ситуация возникнет при сложении двух первых чисел списков, то переносить не нужно. Помогите с кодом, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5):

можно еще попробовать рекурсию:

```
a = [5, 2, 4]
b = [2, 4, 7]

f = lambda x,y=1: x[-1]*y + f(x[:-1],y*10) if x else 0
r = lambda x: r(x//10)+[x%10] if x>9 else [x]

r(f(a)+f(b))  # [7, 7, 1]
```

`f` - рекурсивно конвертируем список в число

`r` - рекурсивно конвертируем число в список

Answer (score 4):

Можно так:

```
lst1 = [5, 2, 4]
lst2 = [2, 4, 7]
res = 0
for i in reversed(range(len(lst1))):
    res += (lst1[i]+lst2[i])*10**(len(lst1)-i-1)
res = list(str(res)[::-1][:len(lst1)])
print(res)
```

Чтобы каждый раз не считать `10**n` заново:

```
lst1 = [5, 2, 4]
lst2 = [2, 4, 7]
res = 0
mult = 1
for i in reversed(range(len(lst1))):
    res += (lst1[i]+lst2[i])*mult
    mult *= 10
res = list(str(res)[::-1][:len(lst1)])
print(res)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! А можно такую строчку добавить, чтобы итоговый результат в виде листа выдавал: x = [int(a) for a in str(res)]

Comment: @user431563 исправил

Comment: А если `lst1 = [9, 2, 4]`

Comment: @splash58 `['1', '1', '7', '1']` . вроде верно

Comment: если такая ситуация возникнет при сложении двух первых чисел списков, то переносить не нужно

Comment: @splash58 спасибо за замечание. исправил

Answer (score 4):

Ещё как вариант:

- переворачиваем оба списка
- перебираем их параллельно
- складываем два числа и предыдущий перенос избытка, если он есть
- остаток по модулю 10 добавляем в выходной список
- избыток переносим в следующий разряд
- в конце обрабатываем случай, когда переполняется самый старший разряд

```py
def add_list(a, b):
    s = []
    i = 0
    for a, b in zip(*map(reversed, (a, b))):
        z = a + b + i
        s.append(z % 10)
        i = z // 10
    if i:
        s.append(i)
    return s[::-1]

a = [5, 2, 4]
b = [2, 4, 7]

print(add_list(a, b))
```

Вывод:

```
[7, 7, 1]
```

Случай, когда списки разного размера, не обрабатывается, но переделать не сложно через `itertools.zip_longest`.

Answer (score 4):

Циферка к циферке - получается число! Осталось просуммировать :)

Длины списков не влияют на результат.

```
list_1 = [5, 2, 4, 5]
list_2 = [9, 4, 7]

value_1 = int(''.join(str(val) for val in list_1))
value_2 = int(''.join(str(val) for val in list_2))

temp = value_1 + value_2
result = list(str(temp))

print(result)
```

Получить нужный фрагмент можно с помощью среза:

```
result = list(str(temp)[-3:])
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
a = [5, 2, 4]
b = [2, 4, 7]
c = [1, 1, 1, 1]

def list_to_int(val: list):
    result = 0

    for i in range(-len(val), 0):
        result += 10 ** abs(i + 1) * val[i]
    return result

def int_to_list(val: int):
    result = []
    while val:
        val, tail = divmod(val, 10)
        result.insert(0, tail)
    return result

def sum_list(*args):

    return int_to_list(
        sum(
            map(
                list_to_int, args
            )
        )
    )

print(
    sum_list(a, b)
)
# [7, 7, 1]

print(
    sum_list(a, b, c)
)
# [1, 8, 8, 2]
```

> Будет работать с любым количеством списков любой длины